# Upcrossings and Limits

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I am reading the proof of theorem 3.8 in "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" from Karatzas and Shreve.

Following is something I don't understand.[image]

Here $U_{[0,n](\alpha,\beta,X(\omega))}$ denotes the number of upcrossings in the interval $[0,n]$ between levels $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by the path $X(\omega)$. I am not sure how $A^{(n)}$ contains the points for which $\liminf$ is stricly less than $\limsup$. Can anyone clarify ? Why do we have upcrossings and not necessarily downcrossings ?

**Definition of $U$ :**

Let $F$ be a finite subset of $I$, then define

$U_F(\alpha,\beta,X(\omega))$ to be number of upcrossings between levels $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the sequence $\{X_f(\omega) :f \in F\}$.

Then $U_I(\alpha,\beta,X(\omega)) = \sup \{U_F(\alpha,\beta,X(\omega): F\text{ is a finite subset of } I\}$.

Comment: Can you please give more details and provide a formal definition of $U$ ? To link $A^{(n)}$ to that set have you tried to start with an $\epsilon-\delta$-definition of continuity of $X$ ? I am pretty sure that this is the way to go. Formalize this and take the negation of it .

Comment: @KurtG. I will try to do that. I have added the definition of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega$ is in the set
$$
\Big\{\omega\in\Omega;\underline{\lim}\limits_{s\uparrow t}X_s(\omega)<\overline{\lim}\limits_{s\uparrow t}X_s(\omega)\,,\text{ for some }t\in[0,n]\Big\}
$$
then there exist two rationals $\alpha<\beta$ such that for some $t\in[0,n]\,,$
$$
\underline{\lim}\limits_{s\uparrow t}X_s(\omega)<\alpha<\beta<\overline{\lim}\limits_{s\uparrow t}X_s(\omega)\,.
$$
By the very definition of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ this means that the path
$s\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ must be infinitely often below $\alpha$ and infinitely often above $\beta$. In other words, the number of upcrossings of $[\alpha,\beta]$ must be infinite. That is $\omega$ is in $A^{(n)}_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Regarding your question about downcrossings: Please repeat in detail the proof of K&S Thm. 3.8 using downcrossings to find that out.

Also in the future: don't post pictures. Type everything in MathJax. Keep defintions self contained. Non one runs around with their copy of K&S all the time.

Comment: @manco : Why did you just delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418774/equivalent-definition-of-stopping-time/4418799#4418799) few minutes after I answered it ?